# CakePhp : Save User Id according to the user selected

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am new to CakePhp. I have a Users Controller and a Records Controller in my cake.The Users Controller is saving the user's details like username etc. Records Controller is saving the other records of the users. Records Controller has one ctp file. In this file, I have a dropdown list showing all the user names from the users controller. A user is selecting his name from the dropdown. A button named checkin is also there. Now I want to save the user's Id in the database according to the user selection when the user click on the CheckIn Button. How to do this ?

Here is my Record Controller Function

```
function record()
{
 $this->loadModel('User');
 $rec = $this->User->find('list', array('fields'=>   array('User.user_id','User.username')));
  $this->set(compact('rec'));
  $this->Record->saveField('in',date("H:i:s"));
  }
  }
  ?>
```

View File

```
   <?php 
   echo $this->Form->input('Select User', array('type'=>'select','options' => $rec,'empty'=>false));
   echo $form->end('CheckIn');?>
```

Comment: I want to save in the Records model which has records named table in the database.

Comment: I want to design now not after 1 month.Thanks for your precious comment. From now please do not comment on my questions because I want answers here not the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You should take 1-------'s advice, learn the basics of CakePHP before you get ahead of yourself and it will stop you getting stuck at these points in the future. Your questions lacks essential details so I'm going to make assumptions.

All you need to do is pass the user ID to the User model when you call `save()`. If you have a select element to select the user name, I recommend doing this:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">First user</option>
    <option value="2">Second user</option>
</select>
```

where the value of the options are the user ID's. Then, make sure the `$this->request->data` array correctly represents the data fields:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1 // From the select element on the form
        [isername] => 'Updated username'
    )
)
```

When you call `$this->User->save($this->request->data);` Cake will know you're updating a record since you passed in the ID.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The user is selecting his name from the dropdown. Now I want to pass his UserId to the Records Controller not to the User's Controller.

Answer (score 1):

```
$rec = $this->User->find('list', array('fields'=>   array('User.user_id','User.username')));
```

You don't have to define the fields for a list query. If the model has it's display title set then that field will be used.

```
class User extends AppModel
{
    //...
    var $displayField = 'username';
}

// then in your controller
$this->set('users',$this->User->find('list'));
```

To create a drop down selection of those users in your view. You use the built in `select()` function.

```
$this->Form->select('user_id',$users);
```

It's important to tell the Form helper what field in the table the input populates. When the form is posted to the controller it will appear in `$this->data` (for Cake 1.x). The standard convention (if a belongs to association) would make the user's field name `user_id` in the `Record` model.

```
function record()
{
    if(!empty($this->data))
    {
        if(!$this->Record->save($this->data))
        {
            die("Failed to save...");
        }
    }
    $this->loadModel('User');
    $this->set('users',$this->User->find('list'));
}
```

Comment: Actually this record function is in Records Controller and I am populating the dropdown with users. I want to save the users Id when the user selects his name from the dropdown and after selecting his name click on the chheck In Button. When they click on the checkin button, I want to save his Id and time in the database table named records which corresponds to the records model and records controller.

Comment: In the dropdown, I am fetching the data from the Users Controller.

Comment: The view file is in records controller

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save userid then

```
 $rec = $this->User->find('list', array('fields'=>   array('User.user_id','User.username')));

 $this->set(compact('rec'));
```

In your view

```
$this->Form->input('User.user_id',array('empty'=>'Select User', 'options'=>$rec));
```

You can collect it in you form action in this way

```
$this->data['User']['user_id']
```

Hope this will work for you

Comment: I want to save the userId in the records table which corresponds to the records controller. I have UserId already in the users table which corresponds to the users controller.

Comment: In records table, I have these three fields:  id, user_id, in

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try this. Hope it will work for me.